# What is the metered connection in Windows 10?

Tags: networking, windows-10

I understand that this option prevents automatic updates if you, for example, connect to a mobile hotspot, so you wouldn't have any surprises on your monthly bill. I see nothing to configure it though.

I am on a metered connection at home (about 150GB/month before they start converting to dial-up speeds - unreal in this day and age). It sounds a lot, but if you have a Netflix connection and several computers, you hit the limit regularly!

Does this Win 10 setting have any effect on my situation (is it manageable somewhere?) or is this simply meant for ad-hoc connections without purpose for permanent connections like a desktop?

Comment: Read [Metered Internet connections: FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/metered-internet-connections-frequently-asked-questions) and [How, When, and Why to Set a Connection as Metered on Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/226722/how-when-and-why-to-set-a-connection-as-metered-on-windows-10/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there are any configurable settings for the metered connection. Having it enabled will limit or disable some internet activities (e.g Windows Update).  It appears that Windows Apps (I presume from the app store) have the ability to limit their internet usage based on this setting too.

I don't believe that for you, this will have any real use.  If you are trying to prevent going over a set limit, you would be better off using a third party traffic limiter such as [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/).

Answer (score 0):

## I am using this setting in a similar situation

My connection is over the mobile data plan, with cap at 10 GB (much more restrictive than yours). I am using this setting to prevent Windows 10 from downloading system and application updates. My particular problem is that the Anniversary update does not install (tried several times, with different hacks and settings to no avail), so it would drain my data plan every month.

As you can read in [How To Geek's article about it](http://www.howtogeek.com/226722/how-when-and-why-to-set-a-connection-as-metered-on-windows-10/), this setting helps by disabling:

- Windows Automatic updates, both direct and peer-to-peer (so you will not be providing updates to others in case you manually download them
- application automatic updates (those through Windows Update and those third party that respect the setting)
- Off-line files will not update either
- Some Windows Store apps will run with limited functionality (specially in background)

Additionally, Start Menu tiles might not update and some applications restrict themselves (e.g. OneDrive for windows 8 does not sync over metered connections, but OneDrive for Windows 10 does now).

#### Shortcommings

This is a non-exhaustive list of what I found out needs be done if you set your usual connection as metered:

1. you'll have to regularly check for updates. In the Windows Update settings (Settings -> System/Update) you can check for updates manually and then click on any you want to download.
2. make sure your antivirus updates regardless of the setting, if not you might want to refrain from this solution. In my case, Avira does update.
3. check for other updates manually. Mozilla apps will update regardless of the setting, but other applications (Microsoft's and many from the Windows Store) will not update.

   1. You might want to undo the setting by the end of the operator's billing cycle, so you allow the system to run as if in non-mettered connection for the last day of the cycle, if there are GBs left, and then set it back to metered (once you have given permissions to the Administrators, it is just `regedit`ing the key, you might even make scripts for that).
   2. Alternatively, you may set your usual connection --say WiFi-- as metered; and when you want your system to run wild and update freely, connect it over something else --say Ethernet-- that still is configured as non-metered.
4. manually check for news and highlights if any of your favorite apps stop showing you the updates you're accustomed to.

If any of these sounds daunting or just too uncomfortable, I'd keep looking for other solutions.

#### How to set it

The way I found to set it in Windows 10 is by editing the registry (so, please apply every and all warnings about manually editing the registry). The mentioned article does not indicate how to do it by editing the registry, but they do have [one other article](http://www.howtogeek.com/262477/how-to-set-an-ethernet-connection-as-metered-in-windows-8-and-10/) that does; additionally, [Windows Central](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-ethernet-connection-metered-windows-10) also explains --quite graphically-- how to do it.

The outline of the steps is as follows:

1. launch the `regedit`
2. find `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost`
3. **give permissions** to <del>yourself</del> Administrators and propagate to all children of that key
4. Change the Owner of that key to the newly granted *Administrators*
5. Set value to `2` for those connections you want to be metered (3G and 4G are already, in my case I set "Ethernet" as metered, since I connect to the mobile via USB).